# Using Adobe Flash Builder, how to make a project that runs on desktop, mobiles and web?

Tags: flash, mobile, adobe, cross-platform, flash-builder

I'm trying out Flash Builder but something bothers me.

Say, you made a mobile application project but wanted to test it as a desktop application, do you have to export/convert the project into desktop application project every time you want to test it?

Although I want my application to be cross-platform, I don't want to have several projects for each platform(web,desktop,mobile etc.

Is there an easier or simpler way to work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way i manage this situation is to create a library project that contains the application; with (eg) a Group as the top level visual component rather than [Windowed]Application.

Then i create a mobile project and include top level group as its only child; and do the same for a desktop project.

So workflow is to code in the library project and debug using either mobile or desktop projects.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I'm going to try myself. Thank you